# c# read write same file more robust way?

Tags: c#, file, networking, io

I'm developing a progress tracking and monitoring type of an application(c# .net 4.5) A single file both gets written and read from a network location.

I'm having trouble (unresponsive UI / Crashes) reading writing that file in such cases:

- if network location is momentarily not responding,
- if network location is reached over internet and there is considerable lag,
- at startup while client firewall kicks in, it grants delayed access to  network resources,

So I'm in need of a more robust way of reading and writing rather than

```
using (StreamWriter wfile = File.AppendText(path))
{
//...
}
using (StreamReader rfile = new StreamReader(path))
{
//...
}
```

Async methods seem to conflict reader and writer threads. What is the best practice and your suggestions over this issue? Thanks

Comment: Could you buffer the content in memory and periodically flush it to the file?

Comment: *Async methods seem to conflict reader and writer threads* what do you mean by that?

Comment: *"(unresponsive UI / Crashes)"* Your problem is from you should not do the file read/stream creation on the UI thread. Put the creation of the stream on a background worker/Task. Also you say *"Async methods seem to conflict reader and writer threads."* what do you mean by that?

Comment: the writer method is already working on a backgroundworker thread and if I async the reader method(ui thread) I'm getting "file is in process by another thread" exception. this is what I meant by "conflicting"

Answer (score 0):

You need a service to resolve the issue where the service does the reading and writing of the file.  Windows does not properly handle the conflicts.  If you don't want to create a service use a database like SQL Server which automatically resolves the conflicts.  By the way, SQL Server is a service.